# Importing .txt data in a particular format

Tags: python

this is a following sample of data

```
"TABITHA","OLLIE","JAIME","WINIFRED"
```

followed by a piece of code that correctly reads it in.

```
with open("names.txt", 'rb') as f:
    data = [map(str, line.split(',')) for line in f]
```

However, this reads it in as a list of lists. The list being only one list 'high',

```
e.g. [["TABITHA", "OLLIE", "JAIME", "WINIFRED"]]
```

and therefore might as well be just a list, not a list of lists. Is there a way to read it in as just a list? The journey of learning continues :- )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "batteries included" [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) (comma-separated values) module.  Despite the name, it can also be configured for other separators and has a number of other options as well.

```
import csv
with open('names.txt','rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        print line
```

Output:

```
['TABITHA', 'OLLIE', 'JAIME', 'WINIFRED']
```

Comment: Ok, so you got the csv to work which is better than me :p. But how do I actually have this become a list I can then use in my module? Right now you're just printing it out

Comment: `line` is the list.  Just use it.  if you want all the lines in the file, use `list(csv.reader(f))` instead of the `for` loop, but you'll get a list of lists again even if you have only one line.  With the `for` loop, you process one line at a time, and you only have one line.

Comment: Wow, I tried it before but didn't realise it had this functionality. So doing just that 'with' and 'for' actually imports line as an entire list. I didn't realise that because there was no obvious code to suggest that. My last question then is - say I don't want to print 'line', I just want to read it in, what sort of filler should I use with Python. Thankyou!

Comment: If you know it is only the one line you could write `line = csv.reader(f).next()` instead of the `for`.

Comment: Awesome that works, in future say I do have multiple lines, what sort of filler would I use? I'm totally starting out learning so I have 1,000,000 questions :p

Comment: Write a function and call `process(line)` instead of `print line`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Functional, "roll-your-own", code:

```
with open("names.txt", 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
       line = line.strip()
       line = [w.replace('"','') for w in line.split(',')]
       print line
```

creates the *list* `line`:

```
['TABITHA', 'OLLIE', 'JAIME', 'WINIFRED']
```

Comment: @downvoter .. this code is functional and meets OP's specifications.

Comment: with open("names.txt", 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
       line = [w.replace('"','') for w in line.split(',')]

also works - no need for the stripping. Thankyou

Comment: Not the downvoter, but if the data has commas between the quotes this doesn't work, which is why it is better to use a tested module like csv instead of roll-your-own.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I agree using the csv module (like you did) is a better approach, but given the data sample (I didn't see any commas between the quotes) and desired output this works - it generates the same output as your solution.

Comment: @BenLucato .. without the `strip()` I get this as the last item: `'WINIFRED\r\n']` so I think the `strip()` is necessary. I do agree that using the CSV module is a better approach in general.

Comment: @MarkTolonen "but if the data has commas between the quotes this doesn't work" .. can you give me an example of this type of data - everything I've tried has worked as well as the CSV version. Perhaps I'm not thinking of the right type of data you had in mind?

Comment: `"TABITHA","OLLIE","JAIME","WINI,FRED"` parses to `['TABITHA', 'OLLIE', 'JAIME', 'WINI', 'FRED']` instead of `['TABITHA', 'OLLIE', 'JAIME', 'WINI,FRED']`.  The `csv` module doesn't treat commas within quotes as a delimiter.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah ok, I see what you are saying .. thanks for taking the time to send an example, I always try to learn as much as I can from alternate solutions so this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read something like this is to use the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).  This will correctly deal with embedded commas that might appear in the quoted values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be foolish and not use a CSV module:

```
sum([line.split(", ") for line in f], [])
```

Edit: What's the matter with my initial data then?

```
>>> f
['TABITHA, OLLIE, JAIME, WINIFRED', 'Spam, Eggs, Dead Parrots']
>>> sum([line.split(", ") for line in f], [])
['TABITHA', 'OLLIE', 'JAIME', 'WINIFRED', 'Spam', 'Eggs', 'Dead Parrots']
```

With a file:

```
$ cat temp.csv
foo, bar, baz
spam, eggs, quux
$ python
>>> f = open("temp.csv")
>>> sum([line.split(", ") for line in f], [])
['foo', 'bar', 'baz\n', 'spam', 'eggs', 'quux\n']
```

(Add in a `map(str.strip, ...)` to get rid of trailing whitespace)

Comment: yields `['"TABITHA","OLLIE","JAIME","WINIFRED"\n']` when I run it.

Comment: Yes, this reads a total of ~45000 items from my data, whilst there should be only ~5000 items